# Unloading Multiple tables in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have to implement a CR, where i have to unload around 180 tables of Redshift cluster. I have all Unload command, which I'm going to execute one by one.

It would be great if I do get some work-around over this issue.

Reference document: [Unloading Data to Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html)

Sample command:

```
unload ('select column1, column2 from table') to 's3://prod/audi/history/20150914/fact_invite2_audi_'
credentials '<>' 
MANIFEST GZIP ESCAPE DELIMITER AS ',' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your actual question? What do you mean by "get some work-around over this issue"? What is your "issue"?

Comment: Hello John,

Can i unload multiple tables in one single command/script ?
If yes, please let me know the way.

I have to unload around 185 tables. As of now i am doing it by running UNLOAD command one by one.

Comment: Hi @RoshanNagpure there are no Redshift commands to unload multiple tables. You will need to write a quick iterator in a scripting language of your choice to create all the necessary statements.

Answer (score 2):

The [Amazon Redshift `UNLOAD` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) only exports the results of one SELECT statement. The statement can reference multiple Redshift tables, but will not export the data as separate outputs.

Some options:

- Send **one request with multiple UNLOAD statements**, separated by semi-colons. They will be executed sequentially, but it's easier to issue.
- **Run simultaneous requests.** Each would need a separate JDBC connection, but the requests would run concurrently, based upon [Workload Management queue configurations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented this with the help of stored procedure.

### What we’ll achieve with this?

1. Unload many tables to S3.
2. Unload all the tables in a specific schema.
3. Unload specific tables in any schema.
4. All the tables in all the schema.

All detailed steps are here: https://thedataguy.in/redshift-unload-multiple-tables-schema-to-s3/